# How to use Conda across users in Mac Terminal

Tags: shell, anaconda, conda

I have two user accounts on my system (MacOS). My main account was **A** and I recently created **B**. I originally installed Anaconda as user **A**, before user **B** was created. I can open Anaconda Navigator in user **B** and use all modules, but when I enter any `conda` commands on the terminal, I get a `command not found: conda` error.

Why is that and what should I do to run Conda from the command line in user **B**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Conda installs, it adds a section of code to the user's `.bash_profile` (or `.zshrc` if using `zsh` shell). Copying that section to the corresponding file in the new user's home may be sufficient to get the `conda` command and `conda activate` working.

You may also want to copy some or all of the settings in the `.condarc` file. For example, you likely want the `pkgs_dirs` configured to point to original user's location (hint: try running `conda config --show-sources` and `conda config --show` to see the current settings).

Comment: Hey merv! Thanks for the answer! There were no .zshrc in the new users folder. So, I copied the .zshrc file entirely from the other user's folder. In addition, I copied the missing lines into the new user's .condarc file. Finally, I copied the environments.txt file from old user's .conda folder to new user's .conda folder. After that, conda command worked on Terminal, but then I got Error 500 when I wanted to open a Jupyter notebook. To solve that, I gave the new user to access the /Users/olduser/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/html folder. Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

The default Anaconda installation is for the Current User only.  To install for all users, you need to click on the relevant button when presented during installation.  For more information, see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/